# find document where item of array equals to a string

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor mongo command tries to get the document with the `emails[0].address == abc@xyz` but it is failing, Any ideas?  thx

`db.users.findOne({'emails[0].address':'abc@xyz.com'}).pretty()`

```js
"emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "abc@xyz.com",
```

Comment: Do you only want to find items where the first email equals the given string or where any of the email addresses matches it?

Comment: @MasterAM Only the first email, but since you asked, it would be nice to know if a given email exists. thx

Comment: simply querying for `email.address` will do the trick. However, note that there is a dedicated method for this, [`Accounts.findUserByEmail`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-findUserByEmail), which takes case sensitivity into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it working please change `emails[0].address` to `emails.0.address`.

Please see the docs on how to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

that will work only if the string you're looking for is the first element of the array. to search through the whole array, you need $elemMatch. e.g.

```
db.users.findOne({emails: {
    $elemMatch: {address: 'abc@xyz.com'}
}})
```